# Text alignment issue with Image

Tags: react-native, react-native-stylesheet

I have been trying to align text with Image horizontally but it should start right below the image if text gets larger than 1 line. I've added view as parent container and gave below styles:

```
footer: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'flex-start',
  }
```

But no luck. Also I've tried giving `flex-wrap: 'wrap'` but that didn't worked as well.

**What I'm getting after my try:**
[image]
**What is my expectation:**
[image]